# UL Testing for low voltage battery powered devices

Tags: batteries

Is UL Testing needed for a 3.6 V battery powered device that is totally enclosed in ABS platstic with no electrical terminals outside?

Comment: It all depends on who you want to sell it to. They will tell you whether they want that kind of certification. There is no blanket answer.

Comment: UL, like other test labs, can test/certify to a wide number of standards.  Exactly which standards you must comply with will depend entirely on what your device does inside its ABS enclosure and where you intend to sell it.

Comment: UL testing is not just about electric shock safety. Safe surface temperatures, flammability and (possibly) toxic smoke hazards are also covered, and some 3.6V battery equipment may have to meet standards in those respects. For my money if it's a CR2032 button cell I wouldn't worry, but a big LiPo cell could be another matter.

Comment: @$Brian Drummond Weren't there special standards for the button cells in regards with short circuits? I've heard that at one time there was a rule for them that you had to use two different elements to prevent short circuit. Also some real-time clocks that are designed to directly connect to battery boast that they passed UL certification and can be used in UL approved designs. DS1307 for example comes to mind.

Comment: I agree with the comments do far. I just want to emphasize that very many battery-powered consumer products receive no UL testing whatsoever. But it depends on the market and purpose of the product.

Comment: Not unless you want to pay lots of money to get it tested.